# Java creating a test file from a jar

Tags: java, file, jar, export

I want to have a java app, where after starting the jar I get a file for example a test.txt within the same folder as the jar.

For example I click on the jar and in the same folder I get a test.txt file.

The below code works in eclipse and creates the file, but after an export to jar, no file is produced.

Would be very happy if you could help.

```
public class FileWriterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "test.txt";
        try(
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        ) {
            writer.write("Hello");
                   } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you running your jar after exporting?

Comment: Use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get the "working" directory reference and make sure it's where you think it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `System.getProperty("user.dir")` you can get the current "working directory".
If you want to create a file in that specific directory you could use the following code:

```
String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File file = new File(working directory + File.separator + "filename.txt");
file.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running as `java -jar yourjar.jar`, it will not take the additional classpath.

You need to add your jar and location where file resided in classpath  and call java command for Main class

example

Linux

```
java  -classpath .:path_dir_with_jar/*:path_to_file MainClass
```

Windows

```
java  -classpath .;path_dir_with_jar/*;path_to_file MainClas
```

Finally can read as

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream("SomeTextFile.txt")
```

;